how to override InputDecorationTheme border color on hover?
I tried to generate theme using the Material theme builder using #EC6164 as the source color but the output of the onError property of the color scheme is Color(0xffffffff)(white). Now the output color of the border of the text field with error is  white, like the screen recording below

I have this theme setup, how i can override the error color on hover without directly changing the colorsheme provided by the material theme builder?
  ThemeData theme(ColorScheme colorScheme) => ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: colorScheme.brightness,
        colorScheme: colorScheme,
        textTheme: textTheme.apply(
          bodyColor: colorScheme.onSurface,
          displayColor: colorScheme.onSurface,
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(

          // how to override the on error color

          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.1),
          filled: true,
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: colorScheme.surface,
        canvasColor: colorScheme.surface,
      );



Try to create a custom TextField with hover using MouseRegion.

You can use error border specifically to define however you want the error border to show. here is an example of it:
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
   
    // Define the border when there is an error
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.red, // Customize the color here
        width: 1.5, // Customize the width if needed
      ),
    ),
  ),

And there are other customization too that you can try.. like this one.
  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.redAccent, // You can adjust the color for focused state if needed
        width: 1.5,
      ),
    ),


is this will change the border color when it's on hover? i see this answer only changing the default error border color
